# Basic Haskell: problems with a function

Tags: haskell

me again with another basic problem I have. I'm using ghci.

I (with help) created this working code:

```
newtype Name = Name String deriving (Show)
newtype Age = Age Int deriving (Show)
newtype Weight = Weight Int deriving (Show)
newtype Person = Person (Name, Age, Weight) deriving (Show)   

isAdult :: Person -> Bool
isAdult (Person(_, Age a, _)) =  a > 18
```

However problems occur when I tried making a more complex function updateWeight that allows the user to change a Person's weight from it's previous value. Can you point out where I have gone wrong?

```
updateWeight :: Person -> Int -> Person
updateWeight (Person(_,_,Weight w) b = (Person(_,_,w+b))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use the `_` placeholder on the right hand side of an expression. You'll have to pass through the unchanged values. Also, you must wrap the result of `w + b` with a `Weight` again. This should work:

```
updateWeight :: Person -> Int -> Person
updateWeight (Person(n, a, Weight w) b = (Person(n, a, Weight (w + b)))
```

You can get rid of the boilerplate of passing through the unchanged values by using [record syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes#Named_Fields_.28Record_Syntax.29) for the  `Person` type.